# How do I convert CPTColor to UIColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, uicolor

I have a `CPTColor` (from `corePlot`). How can I convert the `CPTColor` to a `UIColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTPColor` has a property which allows you to obtain a UIColor object from itself. Assuming your `CTPColor` object is called *myColor*:

```
UIColor myUiColor = myColor.uiColor;
```

This can be found really easily by checking out the documentation for `CTPColor`, found [**here**](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_color.html). Documentation is written for a reason!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Docs for newer versions of Core Plot are now hosted on [GitHub](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/index.html).

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that, Eric. I was unaware of that. Updated my answer.